# The Document for selenium test!

Tags: ruby, selenium

I want to use selenium test to cover my rails project ! but i just find  little documents on selenium test . I want someone to give me some documents for selenium test of all types !like website ,pdf ,text etc.  you can sent them to my gmail     `liwh87@gmail.com`    ,or write  under the question. Thank you ,and best regards!

Answer (score 1):

You might start [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/)